# WildFly (JBoss) Integration with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I am currently trying to integrate WildFly and Eclipse JEE Oxygen 3 with WildFly12.0. I am getting an error I don't understand nor can I find a fix. When in the new server I get the following on the last step: "No valid JREs found for execution environment "JavaSE-1.8" "

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it means you don't have a Java 8 JRE installed, or you didn't set the java environment path correct for eclipse to read.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add JRE 1.8 to your installed JREs and then use it on the build path of your project.

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add

Then add this JRE to your build path

1. Right click on your project
2. Build path -> Configure Build Path
3. Go to Libraries tab
4. Add Library -> JRE System Library
5. Choose JRE 1.8